# JavaScript equivalent of SwingUtilities.invokeLater()

Tags: java, javascript, equivalent, invokelater

Is there any equivalent of Java's `invokeLater()` method of `SwingUtilities` in Javascript?

**UPDATE 1**

So, will `setTimeout()` with zero delay do exactly the same as `invokeLater()`?

Comment: I think you missed the point of @Tomasz's answer: `setTimeout()` will never do the same as `invokeLater()` because it will *block your UI thread* while invoking the delayed function.

Comment: I think the question is whether it will always return immediately and execute its function argument directly from the UI loop, even with an argument of zero, or instead sometimes execute the function immediately.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi so does Swing's invokeLater. That also always runs its argument on the UI thread but it guarantees to always return immediately and perform the execution directly from the event loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you want to run something asynchronously (*later*), try [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)
2. JavaScript is single-threaded. If you want to run some time consuming (CPU-intensive) task outside of the event handler, you can do this using the technique above, however it will still consume event-handling thread (cause your UI to freeze).

It is generally a bad idea to run CPU-intensive tasks inside a browser ([web workers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker) might change this) since they share the same thread as event handlers, making them wait.

#### See also

- [Are there any atomic javascript operations to deal with Ajax's asynchronous nature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266918)

Comment: Will `setTimeout()` with zero delay do exactly the same as `invokeLater()`?

Comment: @Dims, *yes*, it should have been part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tried `setTimeout`, it made the UI give an impression that it was working but somehow it took a long time. Something like this:

```
for (...) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // show a loading icon
        // AJAX call
        // heavy DOM manipulation
    });
}
```

Tried `Promise`. outcome was simply better and faster. So the code is now like this:

```
for (...) {
    var promise = new Promise(function() {
        // show a loading icon
        // AJAX call
        // heavy DOM manipulation
    });
}
```