# Order of keyevents atomic?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events, keyevent

Is the order of `keydown` and `keypress` always atomic? When being in the `keypress` handler, is it guaranteed that the last `keydown` event belongs to the `keypress` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is by nature single threaded. Thus, when one event is dispatched, it is put on the queue until all previous events are processed. Therefore, as long as the browser receives the events in the right order (Dependant on having a sane OS etc), the events you receive are dispatched in the order they happened.

On a related note: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7266985/1702990