# Array created from .get() won't populate html select

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Here's the rundown. I have an external .txt file which has a number of locations (one per line) which I need to have loaded into my script to populate a dropdown. I'm using .get() to pull in the data, and putting it into an array. It LOOKS correct, but the dropdown isn't populated. Doing some tests, I found if I manually populate the array when I declare it the data I declare there loads fine. Also, if I try doing anything to the array such as turning it into a string nothing happens, and if I try checking the length it reports 0. I've tried making a new array and pushing the content of the first into it, but no dice. I've also tried using makeArray, but that didn't work.

Here's my code so far:

```
var siteIdArray = [];
var path = "*snipped*/siteId.text";
var option = "";

$.get(path, function(data)
{
  siteIdArray = data.split("\n");
  console.log(siteIdArray);
});

for (i = 0; i < siteIdArray.length; i++)
{
  option += '<option value="'+ siteIdArray[i] + '">' + siteIdArray[i] + '</option>';
}
$('#siteId').append(option);
```

Here's a test of what my siteIdAarray contains (full array has a total of 62 items):

```
["AN", "AZ", "BA", "CA"]
```

And the siteId.txt looks like this:

```
AN
AZ
BA
CA
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.get` is an async call, you have to do all the work with the response object inside the callback or pass it to another function:

```
$.get(path, function(data)
{
  siteIdArray = data.split("\n");
  console.log(siteIdArray);

  for (i = 0; i < siteIdArray.length; i++)
  {
      option += '<option value="'+ siteIdArray[i] + '">' + siteIdArray[i] + '</option>';
  }
  $('#siteId').append(option);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of that about $.get but it works, and now I know!

Answer (score 1):

[`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) is [asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131991/asynchronous-and-synchronous-terms), so all the code dependant on `siteIdArray` needs to be in the callback function.

What's happening is your code is reaching the for loop but at that stage `sideIdArray` has not yet been populated by the AJAX response, which is why your call to `console.log` works but the rest does not.

Your code updated:

```
var siteIdArray = [];
var path = "*snipped*/siteId.text";
var option = "";

$.get(path, function(data)
{
  siteIdArray = data.split("\n");
  console.log(siteIdArray);

  for (i = 0; i < siteIdArray.length; i++)
  {
    option += '<option value="'+ siteIdArray[i] + '">' + siteIdArray[i] + '</option>';
  }

  $('#siteId').append(option);
});
```