# What is the differnce between synchronus and asynchronus method?

Tags: javascript

What is the differnce between synchronus and asynchronus method?

I found this q/a from [codeverge](http://codeverge.com/asp.net.web-forms/differnce-between-synchronus-and-asynchronu/402028)

When you call a synchronous method, it does the work and then returns the result (success, failure, maybe nothing is returned).

When you call an asychronous method, it returns immediately (and your program can go on its merry way).  When the work is done, it will call a function that you provide.  The works is done in parallel with the program running.

But really **couldn't understand properly**.

Does anyone have clear concept on this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131991/asynchronous-and-synchronous-terms

Comment: oh! thank you I wasn't able to find that.

Comment: @Juhana: The accepted answer in that thread talks about threads, which may further confuse the Op (in context of Javascript). Something which is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963209/does-async-programming-means-multi-threading

Comment: Fortunately there are 8 other answers if the accepted answer doesn't explain it clearly enough.

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Buy a book.

You can go to your local book store, stand a queue, wait while a cashier gets her makeup ready, then pay for it and own it. That will be **synchronous**.

Or, you can order it instantly on Amazon, and go to other things in your life. When it's there, they ring at your door and you get the book **asynchronously**.

Comment: huh! enough clear now. +1

Comment: @Jack humm! confusing.

Comment: +1 for *"..gets her makeup ready.."* :) Now we know why synchronous process blocks the UI thread ;)

Comment: @Jack: well, every analogy is just an analogy. I've never heard of javascript programs hanging around in a pub nearby, so let's assume them to be always "at home".